# Java author array

Tags: java, arrays

My code: I am having trouble in my printAuthors() method and am unable to get the desired output. So when I print it, I get all of the authors details but I just want the name.

My output:

```
Tan Ah Teck (m) at AhTeck@somewhere.com
Paul Tan (m) at Paul@nowhere.com
```

Desired output:

```
Tan Ah Teck 
Paul Tan


    public void printAuthors(){
        for(int i = 0; i < authors.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(ir);
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: What's stopping your from printing the author's name? And what's `ir`?

Comment: [Please share the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Please share code of `Author` class. You have to modify its `toString` method, if you don't want to change `printAuthors` method.
Or you can write something like

```

```
public void printAuthors(){
     for(int i = 0; i < authors.length; ++i){
         System.out.println(authors[i].name);
     }
}
```

```
And you probably have mistaken with `++i` such increment will return increased value, and not current, so you will miss first value in your `for` loop

Comment: I just created an author class from scratch so public class Author {
 String name; 
 String email;
 char gender; 
 
 public Author(String name, String email, char gender){
  this.name = name; 
  this.email = email;
  this.gender = gender; 
 }
}

Comment: *And you probably have mistaken with ++i such increment will return increased value, and not current, so you will miss first value in your for loop.* What???

Comment: Well, the code i wrote should work fine though. Try it out, it will print only names. Replace your `printAuthors` method with mine

Comment: @shmosel this increment will return current value + 1. If razorcode7 wanted to skip first author, well, its fine. But when iterating over array first value is usually included. UPD: If I have mistaken somewhere, sorry my english ;)

Comment: Where is OP using the return value?